# Do i need to convert WGS84 to Mercator's projection for android GPS?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Do I need to convert WGS84 to Mercator's projection when I want to display android GPS fix on Google map? As I know now - theoretically, yes. As GPS fix is in WGS84 and Google and Bing map are using Mercator's projection.

But in past I used coordinates directly from GPS and displayed it on Google map without any converting, and it was all correct - fix was in the place where it actually was. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an Google Maps APi for sure you provide the location in WGS84 decimal degrees.

The mercator projection is an internal transformation of google maps (to trtansform from WGS84 to cartesian flat space and then to screen) , that may be usefull when painting on the map without using the API.

Comment: Thanks but from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes "World coordinates in Google Maps are measured from the Mercator projection's origin" Not clear: when google maps APi are using Mercator and when WSG84? If i type in in google maps coortinanates are it WGS84?

Comment: I looked into the docu: lat and longituide are WGS84 coordinates, Google introduced the term "world coordinates" which they define as the (flat 2-d) coordinate after the projection. The origin (0,0) of their wolrd coordinate system ist the left upper corner of the flat 2d space which starts at longitude = -180, lat = 85. Dependent of what your task, you have API methods to convert between latLong and world and screen coordinates.